# Formatting for express routes in various files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I understand the error but I am just not sure I understand how to properly do what I am trying to do to stay organized.

> Error: MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added.

index.js

```js
//define routes
const userRoutes = require("./api/route/user"); //bring in our user routes
app.use('/', userRoutes);
module.exports = userRoutes;

const clientRoutes = require("./api/route/client");
app.use('/', clientRoutes);
module.exports = clientRoutes;

const contractorSkillRoutes = require("./api/route/clientskill");
app.use('/', contractorSkillRoutes);
module.exports = contractorSkillRoutes;
```

user.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require("../controller/userController");
const auth = require("../../config/auth");

router.post("/login", userController.loginUser);
router.post("/register", auth, userController.registerNewUser);
router.get("/getusers", auth, userController.getAllUsers);
router.get("/authorize", auth, (req, res) => {res.status(200).json({ authorization: true });});
router.post("/deleteuser", auth, userController.deleteUser);
router.post("/edituser", auth, userController.editUser);

module.exports = router;
```

client.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const clientController = require("../controller/clientController");
const auth = require("../../config/auth");

router.get("/getallclients", auth, clientController.getAllClients);
router.post("/newclient", auth, clientController.newClient);
router.post("/getclientbyid", auth, clientController.getClientById);
router.post("/editclient", auth, clientController.editClient);

module.exports = router;
```

You get the idea.

I recognize that I should probably not be using `app.use` several times but I also just don't get how to include all of the files into one use statement. All of the examples I can find are just including all of the routes in one routes file. Should be a simple fix, I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: why are you using `/` path for every route in `index.js`. instead do something like `app.use('/user', userRoutes);` for user and others. so Your final user routes would be like '/user/login' and etc

Comment: @RohitAmbre That fixed it, thank you. However, do you know why it was throwing that particular error?

Comment: if you're adding many listeners to the same event, then it can throws that warning....limit is of 10 and you can also increase the limit.